# R Versions 4.0.3+ 64 bit Refuse to Launch on Windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

After updating R to 4.0.3, and now 4.0.4, I am unable to launch the 64-bit version. The 32-bit version works fine and previous releases work fine in 64-bit.

Launching in RStudio fails as well as running the Rgui directly.

I have seen a lot of posts relating to version issues with Windows 10. I am on Enterprise version 1909, OS build 18363.1379 and am unable to change the Windows 10 version I have.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** I have uninstalled R and RStudio as well as doing a clean reinstall of windows.
I also do not get any error messages or warnings, just a crash or a "Failed to start"

Comment: This seems a bit light on details. Do you get any errors/warnings?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, I do not get any errors from R, just a crash. In RStudio I get "The R Session failed to start" with no error message.

Comment: If you have anything in `.Rprofile` or `.Rdata`, I suggest you move those out of the way and start again. Perhaps there's something in a stored environment that is not transferring over.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I have tried that before and it did not work. Tried it again and still does not open.

Comment: If you go to `cmd`, nav to its directory (e.g., `c:/R/R-4.0.3/bin/x64`) and run `R --vanilla --no-site`, does it work? (No gui, just testing basic stuff.)

Comment: @r2evans It does not work. Tested that it works with R version 4.0.2 to make sure I typed it correctly

Comment: Do you have anything in your anti-virus, firewall, anti-malware, or some other defensive console? (If it's an enterprise computer, it might be a GPO thing, meaning they may need to permit it explicitly.)

Comment: @r2evans Quite possibly, the issue is figuring out what is being blocked so they can allow it. My IT department is not the most helpful when it comes to stuff like this,

Comment: If that's the issue, then you might get a better response to generalize this and ask over at https://superuser.com. For one, I don't know how to identify if or what policy enforcement software might be responsible, whereas there might be somebody in that community with an idea. Sorry, kaz272, I don't know where to go next given the constrained debugging environment (i.e., via short comments). Good luck!

Comment: @kaz272 did you find any solution that worked? I am also having this problem with R 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 (everything appears to work ok with 4.0.2).

Comment: @CopyOfA Unfortunately, no